# Is it possible to change global sound volume in iphone SDK?

Tags: objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0

Is it possible to change global sound volume from our app in iphone SDK?

If yes, how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way you can do that is throught MPVolumeView. There is no such code to make it louder unless the user do it throught the standard component. I think the reason is way it is not only an input control but when you change the volume in the phisical button it is displayed back in the MPVolumeView too.